# c# implement generic of T to avoid extra logic and have cleaner code

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I have the following code using `C# Winforms DataGridView`.

```
 // METHOD TO PASTE DATA INTO GRID
 private void btnPasteCatalog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource source = (BindingSource)gridCatalog.DataSource;
            source.ListChanged -= Source_ListChanged;

            IBindingList dataSource = null;

            BindingList<Models.SetupArea> areaList = null;
            BindingList<Models.SetupDepartment> deptList = null;

            if (source.DataSource is BindingList<Models.SetupArea>)
            {
                dataSource = (BindingList<Models.SetupArea>)source.DataSource;
            }
            else if(source.DataSource is BindingList<Models.SetupDepartment>)
            {
                dataSource = (BindingList<Models.SetupDepartment>)source.DataSource;
            }

            DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
            {
                string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r");
                int j = 0;
                try { j = gridCatalog.CurrentRow.Index; } catch { }

                foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
                {
                    if (source.DataSource is BindingList<Models.SetupArea>)
                    {
                        // i had to use this instead of dataSource because if not I get error
                        areaList = (BindingList<Models.SetupArea>)source.DataSource;

                        areaList.Add(new Models.SetupArea()
                        {
                            Description = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' })[0]
                        });
                    }
                    else if (source.DataSource is BindingList<Models.SetupDepartment>)
                    {
                        // i had to use this instead of dataSource because if not I get error
                        deptList = (BindingList<Models.SetupDepartment>)source.DataSource;

                        deptList.Add(new Models.SetupDepartment()
                        {
                            Description = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' })[0]
                        });
                    }


                    j++;
                }


                // HERE IS WANT TO PASS GENERIC OF T
                // save to database
                if (source.DataSource is BindingList<Models.SetupArea>)
                {
                    // This is wrong it should be only Models.SetupArea
                    SaveCatalog<BindingList<Models.SetupArea>>(areaList);
                }

                // save to database
                if (source.DataSource is BindingList<Models.SetupDepartment>)
                {
                    // This is wrong it should be only Models.SetupArea
                    SaveCatalog<BindingList<Models.SetupDepartment>>(deptList);
                }

                source.ListChanged += Source_ListChanged;
            }
        }

        // SAVE DATA INTO LITEDB DATABASE
        private void SaveCatalog<T>(T data)
        {
            // Open database (or create if doesn't exist)
            using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"SoftCATCovid19.db"))
            {
                string tableName = null;

                switch (cboCatalogs.Text.ToLower())
                {
                    case "area":
                        tableName = "setup_area";

                        break;
                    case "department":
                        tableName = "setup_department";

                        break;
                }

                // T should be either Models.SetupArea or Models.SetupDepartment
                // right now im receiving BindingList<Models.SetupDepartment> and this breaks the code.


                var col = db.GetCollection<T>(tableName);

                var records = data as BindingList<T>;

                col.Insert(data);

            }
        }
```

I would like to use Generic of T instead of doing all my `IF` logic because at the end I could have here more than 10 catalogs and the code will be huge and not maintainable.

The more important thing is that Im using `BindingList` so in order to pass the Generic T to SaveCatalog method I have to pass the class type like `Model.SetupArea` or `Model.SetupDepartment` and that the parameter is also of this type otherwise the code breaks.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use Generic of T instead of doing all my IF logic because at the end I could have here more than 10 catalogs and the code will be huge and not maintainable.

For the `IF`'s part you have to use a reflection with generics combination in order to make the method really generic way:

```cs
private static void AddBindingSource<T>(BindingSource source, string pastedRow)
{
    if (source.DataSource is BindingList<T> areaList)
    {
        var data = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' }).FirstOrDefault();
        areaList.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), data));
    }
}
```

> The more important thing is that Im using BindingList so in order to pass the Generic T to SaveCatalog method I have to pass the class type like Model.SetupArea or Model.SetupDepartment and that the parameter is also of this type otherwise the code breaks.

```cs
AddBindingSource<Models.SetupArea>(new BindingSource(), "test");
```

Hope this helps ))

Answer (score 0):

May be you just need to redefine `SaveCatalog` as follow:

```
// SAVE DATA INTO LITEDB DATABASE
private void SaveCatalog<T>(BindingList<T> data)
{
  // Open database (or create if doesn't exist)
  using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"SoftCATCovid19.db"))
  {
    string tableName = GetTableName(data);

    var col = db.GetCollection<T>(tableName);
    foreach(var entry in data)
    {
      col.Insert(entry);
    }

  }
}

string GetTableName<T>(BindingList<T> data)
{
  switch (data)
  {
    case BindingList<Models.SetupArea> _:
      return "setup_area";
    case BindingList<Models.SetupDepartment> _:
      return "setup_department";

    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

Then you don't need to do the `if` anymore and only call `SaveCatalog` as follow:

```
SaveCatalog<Models.SetupArea>(areaList);

SaveCatalog<Models.SetupDepartment>(deptList);
```